# Find Min/Max Date Range based on Dummy Columns and sequential dates

Tags: sql, teradata

I have the following table.  I need to find the min/max date of each "Seq" column where there is a 1 or consecutive 1's.  There can only be one "1" in each row

```
Animal  Calendar_Date   SeqA    SeqB    SeqC    SeqD    SeqE
Cat     2/5/2017        0       0       0       1       0
Cat     2/6/2017        1       0       0       0       0
Cat     2/7/2017        1       0       0       0       0
Cat     2/8/2017        1       0       0       0       0
Cat     2/9/2017        1       0       0       0       0
Cat     2/10/2017       0       0       0       0       1
Cat     2/11/2017       0       0       0       0       1
Cat     2/12/2017       0       0       0       0       1
Cat     2/13/2017       0       0       0       0       1
Dog     2/5/2017        1       0       0       0       0
Dog     2/6/2017        1       0       0       0       0
Dog     2/7/2017        0       1       0       0       0
Dog     2/8/2017        0       1       0       0       0
Dog     2/9/2017        1       0       0       0       0
Dog     2/10/2017       1       0       0       0       0
Dog     2/11/2017       0       0       0       1       0
Dog     2/12/2017       0       0       0       1       0
Dog     2/13/2017       0       0       0       1       0
```

The desired result would like this.  I have tried using row_number, rank, and dense_rank but have not been able to crack this.

```
Animal  Sequence    min         Max
Cat     D           2/5/2017    2/5/2017
Cat     A           2/6/2017    2/9/2017
Cat     E           2/10/2017   2/13/2017
Dog     A           2/5/2017    2/6/2017
Dog     B           2/7/2017    2/8/2017
Dog     A           2/9/2017    2/10/2017
Dog     D           2/11/2017   2/13/2017
```

The answer below from dnoeth worked.  However, there were some instances in my data set where an `Animal` and `Calendar_Date` had more than one `Seq` populated with a `1`.  This meant it was not a unique `Seq` per `Animal` per `Calendar_Date`.  I had to revise the code and run it fives times (one for each `Seq`) and `union` them together as can bee seen below.

```
SELECT Animal,
   cast(Min(Trim(Both ',' FROM Seq)) as varchar(8)) as POS_Type, 
   Min(Calendar_Date) as Min_Date, 
   Max(Calendar_Date) as Max_Date
FROM
 (
   SELECT Animal, Calendar_Date, Seq,
      -- calculate groups of consecutive values
      Sum(flag)
      Over (PARTITION BY Animal
            ORDER BY Calendar_Date
            ROWS Unbounded Preceding) AS grp
   FROM
    (
           SELECT Animal, Calendar_Date,
         -- combine all columns into one
         CASE WHEN SeqA = 1 THEN 'SeqA' ELSE null END 
--         CASE WHEN SeqB = 1 THEN 'SeqB' ELSE null END ||
--         CASE WHEN SeqC = 1 THEN 'SeqC' ELSE null END ||
--         CASE WHEN SeqD = 1 THEN 'SeqD' ELSE null END ||
--         CASE WHEN SeqE = 1 THEN 'SeqE' ELSE null END 
         AS Seq,
         -- check if current and previous row are different
         CASE WHEN Min(Seq) -- or LAG in TD16.10
              Over (PARTITION BY Animal
                    ORDER BY Calendar_Date
                    ROWS BETWEEN 1 Preceding AND 1 Preceding) = Seq
              THEN 0
              ELSE 1
         END AS flag
      FROM   Table_A 

        --and SeqA = 1
    ) AS dt
      where seq is not null
 ) AS dt

GROUP BY Animal, grp

Union

SELECT Animal,
   Min(Trim(Both ',' FROM Seq)) as POS_Type, 
   Min(Calendar_Date) as Min_Date, 
   Max(Calendar_Date) as Max_Date
FROM
 (
   SELECT Animal, Calendar_Date, Seq,
      -- calculate groups of consecutive values
      Sum(flag)
      Over (PARTITION BY Animal
            ORDER BY Calendar_Date
            ROWS Unbounded Preceding) AS grp
   FROM
    (
           SELECT Animal, Calendar_Date,
         -- combine all columns into one
--         CASE WHEN SeqA = 1 THEN 'SeqA' ELSE null END 
         CASE WHEN SeqB = 1 THEN 'SeqB' ELSE null END 
--         CASE WHEN SeqC = 1 THEN 'SeqC' ELSE null END ||
--         CASE WHEN SeqD = 1 THEN 'SeqD' ELSE null END ||
--         CASE WHEN SeqE = 1 THEN 'SeqE' ELSE null END 
         AS Seq,
         -- check if current and previous row are different
         CASE WHEN Min(Seq) -- or LAG in TD16.10
              Over (PARTITION BY Animal
                    ORDER BY Calendar_Date
                    ROWS BETWEEN 1 Preceding AND 1 Preceding) = Seq
              THEN 0
              ELSE 1
         END AS flag
      FROM   Table_A 

        --and SeqA = 1
    ) AS dt
      where seq is not null
 ) AS dt

GROUP BY Animal, grp

Union

SELECT Animal,
   Min(Trim(Both ',' FROM Seq)) as POS_Type, 
   Min(Calendar_Date) as Min_Date, 
   Max(Calendar_Date) as Max_Date
FROM
 (
   SELECT Animal, Calendar_Date, Seq,
      -- calculate groups of consecutive values
      Sum(flag)
      Over (PARTITION BY Animal
            ORDER BY Calendar_Date
            ROWS Unbounded Preceding) AS grp
   FROM
    (
           SELECT Animal, Calendar_Date,
         -- combine all columns into one
--         CASE WHEN SeqA = 1 THEN 'SeqA' ELSE null END 
--         CASE WHEN SeqB = 1 THEN 'SeqB' ELSE null END 
         CASE WHEN SeqC = 1 THEN 'SeqC' ELSE null END 
--         CASE WHEN SeqD = 1 THEN 'SeqD' ELSE null END 
--         CASE WHEN SeqE = 1 THEN 'SeqE' ELSE null END 
         AS Seq,
         -- check if current and previous row are different
         CASE WHEN Min(Seq) -- or LAG in TD16.10
              Over (PARTITION BY Animal
                    ORDER BY Calendar_Date
                    ROWS BETWEEN 1 Preceding AND 1 Preceding) = Seq
              THEN 0
              ELSE 1
         END AS flag
      FROM   Table_A 

        --and SeqA = 1
    ) AS dt
      where seq is not null
 ) AS dt

GROUP BY Animal, grp

Union

SELECT Animal,
   Min(Trim(Both ',' FROM Seq)) as POS_Type, 
   Min(Calendar_Date) as Min_Date, 
   Max(Calendar_Date) as Max_Date
FROM
 (
   SELECT Animal, Calendar_Date, Seq,
      -- calculate groups of consecutive values
      Sum(flag)
      Over (PARTITION BY Animal
            ORDER BY Calendar_Date
            ROWS Unbounded Preceding) AS grp
   FROM
    (
           SELECT Animal, Calendar_Date,
         -- combine all columns into one
--         CASE WHEN SeqA = 1 THEN 'SeqA' ELSE null END 
--         CASE WHEN SeqB = 1 THEN 'SeqB' ELSE null END 
--         CASE WHEN SeqC = 1 THEN 'SeqC' ELSE null END 
         CASE WHEN SeqD = 1 THEN 'SeqD' ELSE null END 
--         CASE WHEN SeqE = 1 THEN 'SeqE' ELSE null END 
         AS Seq,
         -- check if current and previous row are different
         CASE WHEN Min(Seq) -- or LAG in TD16.10
              Over (PARTITION BY Animal
                    ORDER BY Calendar_Date
                    ROWS BETWEEN 1 Preceding AND 1 Preceding) = Seq
              THEN 0
              ELSE 1
         END AS flag
      FROM   Table_A 

        --and SeqA = 1
    ) AS dt
      where seq is not null
 ) AS dt

GROUP BY Animal, grp

Union

SELECT Animal,
   Min(Trim(Both ',' FROM Seq)) as POS_Type, 
   Min(Calendar_Date) as Min_Date, 
   Max(Calendar_Date) as Max_Date
FROM
 (
   SELECT Animal, Calendar_Date, Seq,
      -- calculate groups of consecutive values
      Sum(flag)
      Over (PARTITION BY Animal
            ORDER BY Calendar_Date
            ROWS Unbounded Preceding) AS grp
   FROM
    (
           SELECT Animal, Calendar_Date,
         -- combine all columns into one
--         CASE WHEN SeqA = 1 THEN 'SeqA' ELSE null END 
--         CASE WHEN SeqB = 1 THEN 'SeqB' ELSE null END 
--         CASE WHEN SeqC = 1 THEN 'SeqC' ELSE null END 
--         CASE WHEN SeqD = 1 THEN 'SeqD' ELSE null END 
         CASE WHEN SeqE = 1 THEN 'SeqE' ELSE null END 
         AS Seq,
         -- check if current and previous row are different
         CASE WHEN Min(Seq) -- or LAG in TD16.10
              Over (PARTITION BY Animal
                    ORDER BY Calendar_Date
                    ROWS BETWEEN 1 Preceding AND 1 Preceding) = Seq
              THEN 0
              ELSE 1
         END AS flag
      FROM   Table_A 

        --and SeqA = 1
    ) AS dt
      where seq is not null
 ) AS dt

GROUP BY Animal, grp
```

Comment: You might consider showing your code to us so we can check it out. Otherwise, it looks like you're saying "Do this for me"

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add the tag for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `db2`, `sql-server`, ...

Comment: Show what you tried. People like some evidence of prior effort, so they don't just end up doing all of someone's work for them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need nested OLAP-functions:

```
SELECT Animal,
   Min(Trim(Both ',' FROM Seq)), 
   Min(Calendar_Date), 
   Max(Calendar_Date) 
FROM
 (
   SELECT Animal, Calendar_Date, Seq,
      -- calculate groups of consecutive values
      Sum(flag)
      Over (PARTITION BY Animal
            ORDER BY Calendar_Date
            ROWS Unbounded Preceding) AS grp
   FROM
    (
      SELECT Animal, Calendar_Date,
         -- combine all columns into one
         CASE WHEN SeqA = 1 THEN 'A' ELSE ',' END ||
         CASE WHEN SeqB = 1 THEN 'B' ELSE ',' END ||
         CASE WHEN SeqC = 1 THEN 'C' ELSE ',' END ||
         CASE WHEN SeqD = 1 THEN 'D' ELSE ',' END ||
         CASE WHEN SeqE = 1 THEN 'E' ELSE ',' END AS Seq,
         -- check if current and previous row are different
         CASE WHEN Min(Seq) -- or LAG in TD16.10
              Over (PARTITION BY Animal
                    ORDER BY Calendar_Date
                    ROWS BETWEEN 1 Preceding AND 1 Preceding) = Seq
              THEN 0
              ELSE 1
         END AS flag
      FROM tab
    ) AS dt
 ) AS dt
GROUP BY Animal, grp
```

Comment: This worked! I think I need to brush up on my `Over (Partition...` coding skills.  That piece was new to me.  I did find that I had some instances where `SeqA` and `SeqB` both had a `1` which caused an additional `seq`.  I solved that by running the SQL 5 times selecting only 1 `CASE WHEN SeqA = 1 THEN 'A' ELSE ',' END ||`, respectively together with unions.

Comment: @AlmostThere: And you want to get two results when there are two `1`? Instead of 4 `union`s it might be more efficient to `cross join` to a table with 5 rows in it (or depending on your release use `[TD_]UNPIVOT`)

Answer (score 1):

Since you have only five columns, one approach is to hand-unpivot them, and do a simple `GROUP BY` to get the results:

```
SELECT Animal, Sequence, MIN(Calendar_Date), MAX(Calendar_Date)
FROM (
    SELECT Animal, 'A' AS Sequence, Calendar_Date FROM MyTable WHERE SeqA=1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT Animal, 'B' AS Sequence, Calendar_Date FROM MyTable WHERE SeqB=1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT Animal, 'C' AS Sequence, Calendar_Date FROM MyTable WHERE SeqC=1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT Animal, 'D' AS Sequence, Calendar_Date FROM MyTable WHERE SeqD=1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT Animal, 'E' AS Sequence, Calendar_Date FROM MyTable WHERE SeqE=1
) dt
GROUP BY Animal, Sequence
```

Answer (score 0):

Given your data, this might be the most efficient:

```
select animal,
       (case when seqA = 1 then 'A'
             when seqB = 1 then 'B'
             when seqC = 1 then 'C'
             when seqD = 1 then 'D'
             when seqE = 1 then 'E'
        end) as sequence,
       min(calendar_date), max(calendar_date)     
from t
group by seqA, seqB, seqC, seqD, seqE;
```

This works because exactly one of the "seq" columns has a value in each row.

To be honest, I would recommend adding a computed column to the table and using that:

```
alter table animal
    add sequence as (case when seqA = 1 then 'A'
                          when seqB = 1 then 'B'
                          when seqC = 1 then 'C'
                          when seqD = 1 then 'D'
                          when seqE = 1 then 'E'
                     end);
```

Then you can just do:

```
select animal, sequence, min(calendar_date), max(calendar_date)     
from t
group by animal, sequence;
```

Unfortunately, Teradata does not support computed columns.  The Teradata tag was added after I originally answered.  However, you can use a view for much the same effect.

Comment: Thanks! I have not tried this yet but will do so on Monday!